# Custom theme for spinner dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I would like to customize the appearance of the dialog that appears when I click on the spinner in spinnermode=dialog.
I want to use a dialog fragment but I find no documentation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. The appearance is fixed to give it the feel of the operating system.  You would have to create your own spinner to do this which isn't easy but also not too difficult if the lists in your spinner won't get so large that it takes up all the phone's memory.  Just make a control that can scroll vertically.